# Selecting <select> option with unicode characters by typing

Tags: html, angular, drop-down-menu

I have a drop down list of countries, where each entry consists of the country flag and then the country name. This is an excerpt of my drop down:

```
<select>
    <optgroup label="Asia">
        <option label=" Afghanistan" value="string:Afghanistan"> Afghanistan</option>
        <option label=" Armenia" value="string:Armenia"> Armenia</option>
        <option label=" Azerbaijan" value="string:Azerbaijan"> Azerbaijan</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Europe">
        <option label=" Åland" value="string:Åland"> Åland</option>
        <option label=" Albania" value="string:Albania"> Albania</option>
        <option label=" Andorra" value="string:Andorra"> Andorra</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

When I try to find an entry in the drop down by typing, nothing happens. When I get rid of the flags it does work, but I'm still not able to select a country like Åland, thanks to the Å.

Is there some way to tell the browser to ignore the flags when searching? Or would it have to be a custom solution?

This whole select is generated by angular using `ng-options`. Just in case it is needed, this is the array expression in use:

```
ng-options = "selectionValue.name as vm.getCountryDisplayName(selectionValue) group by vm.mmTranslate.tr(vm.getCountryElementGroup(selectionValue)) for selectionValue in vm.countries"
```

The list of countries in `vm.countries` does NOT have the flags, they're added here in the expression via the `vm.getCountryDisplayName` function. `vm.getCountryElementGroup` retrieves the continent of the country.

I couldn't really try anything else because searching for this specific issue yielded only minimal search results, none of which were helpful. I tried modifying the `label` and `value` options, but it seems like the Browser is always using the `label` attribute to do the search.